# how to enable authentication in MongoDB in GKE service

Tags: mongodb, authentication, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

For our Database we have opted for self deployed mongodb and configured it as a service over GKE's managed mongoDB Atlas database. 
however, how to enable authentication as we do in classical deployment? to make use of user authentication.

neither we are able to login to the official mongo image, nor use editor to set the Authentication Flag to **True**

Tried copying the mongoDB config file to local machine to make required changes and replacing it in the image back again, `kubectl copy` require tar archive utility which mongo official image doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

We can use kubernetes provided args flag to start mongo server with authentication enabled, so user based authentication can be utilised for restricting the access to DB.

in MongoDB Deployment manifest just pass **"--auth"**

```
      containers:
      - name: mongo
        image: mongo
        args: ["--auth"]
```

as usual access the db using connection string:
`mongodb://USR:PWD@IP:PORT`

from Robo 3t put load balancer service IP and mongo standard port: 27017